# What property controls the SubForm color variations?

Tags: forms, ms-access

Have a subform that is set to continuous. Every other record has a different color. How do I set this value (the toggle color)?

See attached for more details.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Form's Section `Details` [Section.AlternateBackColor Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821441.aspx) to determent same (or other) color for Alternate record.

Comment: Thank you very much